FindRoot: Is it a zero or a very small value?
I want to solve the following problem: Given a complex matrix $m=\textbf{m}(J, ω)$, with $J, ω \in \mathbb R$, find $λ$ and $ω$ such that
$$\det[\textbf{m} (J, ω)] = 0$$
I tried to solve it with FindRoot. I've found a solution with specific initial values $(J_c,\omega_c)$, but it works only with MachinePrecision->13 and not grater MachinePrecision. Moreover, when I test the solution, it gives me back a zero with a low accuracy, about $10^-3$.
My question is the following: is it possible that FindRoot finds points which are not actual zeros of the function but point for which the function is very small?
How can I distinguish a zero for a "almost zero" numerically?
d = Rationalize[5/10^6]; \[Tau] = Rationalize[0.1]; L = Rationalize[15/10^3]; h = Rationalize[50/10^6]; \[Xi] = Rationalize[0.001]; \[Rho] = Rationalize[1400]; 
  \[CapitalGamma] = Rationalize[0.001]; c = Rationalize[0.05]; Ee = Rationalize[10^8]; w = Rationalize[10^(-3)]; 
A = Rationalize[w*h]; \[CapitalIota] = Rationalize[w*(h^3/12)]; B = Rationalize[Ee*\[CapitalIota]]; \[Alpha] = Rationalize[(d/2)*(2*d - h - Exp[-h/d]*(2*d + h))]; 
  \[Lambda] = Rationalize[c*\[CapitalGamma]*\[Alpha]*(12/h^3)]; 

m2[\[Beta]j_, \[CapitalLambda]_, \[Sigma]_] = ( \[Beta]j^3 - \
\[CapitalLambda] \[Beta]j^2)
m3[\[Beta]j_, \[CapitalLambda]_, \[Sigma]_] = ( \[Beta]j^2 - \
\[CapitalLambda] \[Beta]j) Exp[\[Beta]j L]; 
m4[\[Beta]j_, \[CapitalLambda]_, \[Sigma]_] = ( \[Beta]j - \
\[CapitalLambda]) Exp[\[Beta]j L]; 

(*To find \[Beta]j (j=1,2,3,4) we solve a polynomial equation.*)
eigen[\[CapitalLambda]_, \[Sigma]_] = 
  FullSimplify[
   B ( x^4 - \[CapitalLambda] x^3) + \[Sigma] (\[Xi] + \[Rho] A \
\[Sigma])];

root = Simplify[Solve[eigen[\[CapitalLambda], \[Sigma]] == 0, x]];
xx[\[CapitalLambda]_, \[Sigma]_] = x /. root;

\[CapitalLambda]lin[J_, \[Sigma]_] = 
 FullSimplify[\[Lambda] J /(1/\[Tau] + \[Sigma])]

m[\[CapitalLambda]_, \[Sigma]_] = {{m2[
     xx[\[CapitalLambda], \[Sigma]][[1]], \[CapitalLambda], \[Sigma]],
     m2[xx[\[CapitalLambda], \[Sigma]][[
      2]], \[CapitalLambda], \[Sigma]], 
    m2[xx[\[CapitalLambda], \[Sigma]][[
      3]], \[CapitalLambda], \[Sigma]], 
    m2[xx[\[CapitalLambda], \[Sigma]][[
      4]], \[CapitalLambda], \[Sigma]]}, {1, 1, 1, 
    1}, {m3[xx[\[CapitalLambda], \[Sigma]][[
      1]], \[CapitalLambda], \[Sigma]], 
    m3[xx[\[CapitalLambda], \[Sigma]][[
      2]], \[CapitalLambda], \[Sigma]], 
    m3[xx[\[CapitalLambda], \[Sigma]][[
      3]], \[CapitalLambda], \[Sigma]], 
    m3[xx[\[CapitalLambda], \[Sigma]][[
      4]], \[CapitalLambda], \[Sigma]]}, {m4[
     xx[\[CapitalLambda], \[Sigma]][[1]], \[CapitalLambda], \[Sigma]],
     m4[xx[\[CapitalLambda], \[Sigma]][[
      2]], \[CapitalLambda], \[Sigma]], 
    m4[xx[\[CapitalLambda], \[Sigma]][[
      3]], \[CapitalLambda], \[Sigma]], 
    m4[xx[\[CapitalLambda], \[Sigma]][[
      4]], \[CapitalLambda], \[Sigma]]}};



detexp[J_, \[Sigma]_] = 
  Det[m[\[CapitalLambda]lin[J, \[Sigma]], \[Sigma]]]/10^12;

det[J_, \[Omega]_] = detexp[J, I \[Omega]];

Jc = 4.5*10^3 // Rationalize;
\[Omega]c = 15;

firstmode = FindRoot[{Re[det[J, \[Omega]]] == 0, Im[det[J, \[Omega]]] == 0}, {J, 
  Jc}, {\[Omega], \[Omega]c}, WorkingPrecision -> 13]

(*out {J -> 4397.165861009, \[Omega] -> 14.81874398305}*)

{J1, \[Omega]1} = {J, \[Omega]} /. firstmode;

det[J1, \[Omega]1]

(*out 0.*10^-3 + 0.*10^-3 I*)



PS. I asked a similar question
How can I improve the accuracy of FindRoot for a complex equation?
and tried to implement the old suggestions, but the question here is slightly different.
Thank you!

First: You cannot have _  like \[Omega]_c in variable names in MMA. Second: Rationalize does noting to values that are already rational and only makes people question that and other things in your code. Third {Re[det[J, \[Omega]]]==0,Im[det[J, \[Omega]]]==0} seems like det[J,\[Omega]]]==0 Fourth: If you want an exact zero then I'd try eliminating all decimal points and possibly simplifying the problem a little and finally ask Reduce to find the exact solutions and see what happens.

Hi, thank you for your answer. The first thing is now correct. The second thing: I see what you mean, but it should not affect the result. The third thing: the two equations are needed since we have two unknowns $(J,\omega)$, and hence two equations to solve. Since the determinant is complex, I took the real and the imaginary part of it.

Why don't you like the answers you get with higher WorkingPrecision?  They certainly get the determinant closer to zero.

I didn't get the exactly same result as you report, but I got something that needed fixing.  It seems a WorkingPrecision needs to be much higher than the AccuracyGoal for this problem.
firstmode = 
  FindRoot[{Re[det[J, \[Omega]]] == 0, Im[det[J, \[Omega]]] == 0}, {J,
     Jc}, {\[Omega], \[Omega]c}, AccuracyGoal -> 16, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 64];
{J1, \[Omega]1} = {J, \[Omega]} /. firstmode;

N@det[J1, \[Omega]1]
det[N@J1, N@\[Omega]1]
(*
-2.89809*10^-18 - 8.48501*10^-17 I
-3.41099*10^-8 - 1.30445*10^-8 I
*)

The last line shows the loss of accuracy when the high-precision result is rounded to machine precision.
